# PowerShell Remote Registry

Tags: registry, remote-access, powershell-3.0

I have the following code, which checks the local registry for the All Program list of displaynames, and gives and 'if' statement for alerting if Symantec is installed.

```
$List = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*

if ($List.displayname -Match "Symantec")
{ Write-Host "Symantec is installed." -ForegroundColor Green }
else
{ Write-Host "Symantec is not installed." -ForegroundColor Red }
```

Can someone please tell me how I get this code to check on remote servers, using Remote Registry?

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your script into an invoke-command :

```
icm -ComputerName computer1 -ScriptBlock { 
    $List = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*

    if ($List.displayname -Match "Symantec")
    { Write-Host "Symantec is installed." -ForegroundColor Green }
    else
    { Write-Host "Symantec is not installed." -ForegroundColor Red }
}
```

Comment: FYI, the invoke-command will only work if remoting is enabled.  Which could be a security issue.  (Probably not, since it's enabled on Windows Server 2012 by default).  By default, on a lot of machines (Windows 7, for instance, as well as Pre-WS2012), it's not enabled.